# Fontawesome latest version 4.0.3 - won't show icons

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons, font-awesome

Hi i just included the latest verison of `fontawesome` css , downloaded zip , extracted into vendor/ and linked in html, i can see link is ok from page source i can click and see the file opening (`font-awesome.min.css`)

```
<link href='/vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

But it doesn't shows the icons in html!

> I see blank square instead of the icon

How is this possible?

If i use the old version of fontawesome i can see fonts!!

I looked at fonts and they are there in fonts/ folder so i can't see the problem :(

[image]

Comment: Check the path to the fonts file inside the CSS file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you upgraded from 3 to 4? If so, the syntax has changed completely. What used to be:

```
<i class="icon-name"></i>
```

Is now:

```
<i class="fa fa-icon-name"></i>
```

Refer to [Font-Awesome's *What's New* page](http://fontawesome.io/whats-new/) for more info.

Comment: oh gosh a typo i forgot the .fa so .fa.fa-icon i only used .fa-icon :/